# Run an Windows 8.1 Simulator on a Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Can I run the Windows 8.1 simulator on a Windows 10 machine? I need to test on Windows 8.1, but I'm no longer able to do it, since I upgraded to Windows 10 and installed the Windows 10 SDK and simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The simulator isn't an emulator: It simulates resolution and input through a terminal server session connected back to the local host running the local OS.

The Windows Phone emulators are different. They are hyper-v images of the target mobile OS and so don't need to match the host OS.

Comment: I thought so, but really hoped there is a way to do it. Now that the Windows 10 is out we need to support 8.1 and 10 in the same time, and I can't actually test the 8.1 app on a 8.1 machine. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You can run Windows 8.1 in a VM on your Windows 10 machine.